# Maven antrun move not deleting source file

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

Developing on Windows 10 I have a Java project in Maven that has a Linux "launcher" shell script for the FooBar utility stored in the repository at `src/bin/foobar.sh`. It uses resource filtering to substitute in the correct executable JAR path so that what gets built is a `foobar.sh` script that launches the executable JAR in the same directory.

The POM uses `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8` to enable the executable flag on the `foobar.sh` script in the `target/bin` directory (which has been already been copied using Maven resource filtering, with that directory path stored in the `${binOutputDirectory}` property):

```
<chmod dir="${binOutputDirectory}" includes="**/*.sh" perm="+x" />
```

Then it renames the `foobar.sh` file to simply `foobar` (i.e. it removes the extension) to follow best practices for shell scripts:

```
<move todir="${binOutputDirectory}">
  <fileset dir="${binOutputDirectory}">
    <include name="**/*.sh" />
  </fileset>
  <mapper type="glob" from="*.sh" to="*" />
</move>
```

You can see e.g. [`globalmentor-root` `pom.xml` at `c31ae410143f86ebf2bf10467214214d87b2eb61`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/globalmentor/globalmentor-root/c31ae410143f86ebf2bf10467214214d87b2eb61/pom.xml) for the full POM source code. Actual child POMs will simply enable the AntRun operations by providing their executions an appropriate phase like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>set-shell-scripts-executable</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>remove-shell-script-extensions</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The essential part of that is working fine, and I wind up with a `foobar` file in my distributable ZIP file, with its executable flag enabled as desired. Unfortunately I also wind up with the original `foobar.sh` file as well, and I can see in `target/bin` (where the `.sh` extension gets removed) that both files are there as well. So it would appear that AntRun `<move>` is behaving as `<copy>`.

To see this in action, build the [Guise Mummy 0.1.0](https://github.com/globalmentor/guise/releases/tag/v0.1.0) project and look in the `cli/target/bin` directory; you'll see that `guise.sh` has not been deleted.

To work around the problem, I can add an extraneous `<delete>` command; this will successfully remove `foobar.sh`. (The difference in `<fileset>` syntax is irrelevant; I switched only because it was more concise.)

```
<move todir="${binOutputDirectory}">
  <fileset dir="${binOutputDirectory}" includes="**/*.sh"/>
  <mapper type="glob" from="*.sh" to="*" />
</move>
<delete>
  <fileset dir="${binOutputDirectory}" includes="**/*.sh"/>
</delete>
```

Why is AntRun `<move>` by itself not removing the original `target/bin/foobar.sh` file after it copies it to `target/bin/foobar` as part of the move operation?

Comment: I would let do the maven-assembly-plugin do the that work...

Comment: Your `pom.xml` looks quite complex. I'm not 100% convinced the `maven-antrun-plugin` does not move the file. Have you tried to extract only `maven-antrun-plugin` and your shell file to validate it's the antrun plugin and not something else.

Comment: @asbachb, as I just added to the question, if you're "not 100% convinced" this is happening you can download the [Guise Mummy 0.1.0](https://github.com/globalmentor/guise/releases/tag/v0.1.0) project and see for yourself that `cli/target/bin/guise.sh` is not being deleted. If I've made a mistake in Maven/AntRun, I'd love to know it!

Comment: I don't say it does not happen. I just wanted to ensure that this could be reproduced with a plain project with just the `maven-antrun-plugin` configured.

Comment: Did you try to run maven with -X in order to view if there is some other plugin that do the copy after move? I saw that in the list of plugin there is the assembly plugin, did you check assembly file?

Comment: You could use verbose attribute on move to log the files that are being moved. It could help to debug.

Comment: Reading pom in your project I did not found any error. So  take a look to the ant move source code and I see that it is used sourceFile.renameTo(destFile) that is platform dependent, did you build on windows? Did you use some symbolic link in your filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:3.1.0` seems to have fixed the problem. When I created this question I had been using v1.8. I can only suppose that `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8` is buggy.

Answer (score -1):

Noticed in the `pom`, within the `antrun` goals, you are modifying permissions of the `.sh` script. This does not confirm if the shell script is `writeable`, it may be `read-only`:

```xml
<execution>
  <id>set-shell-scripts-executable</id>
  <!--
  Enable execute permission for the shell scripts in `${binOutputDirectory}`.
  Enable by specifying a phase (e.g. `process-resources`) in child POM.
  -->
  <phase>none</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>run</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <target>
      <chmod dir="${binOutputDirectory}" includes="**/*.sh" perm="+x" />
    </target>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

Try the following, apply the `overwrite` attribute, like so:

> (**overwrite** *overwrite existing files even if the destination files are newer*)

```xml
<move todir="${binOutputDirectory}" overwrite="true">
  <fileset dir="${binOutputDirectory}">
    <include name="**/*.sh" />
  </fileset>
  <mapper type="glob" from="*.sh" to="*" />
</move>
```

If that does not work, also add the `force` attribute, like so:

> (**force** *Overwrite read-only destination files*)

```xml
<move todir="${binOutputDirectory}" overwrite="true" force="true">
  <fileset dir="${binOutputDirectory}">
    <include name="**/*.sh" />
  </fileset>
  <mapper type="glob" from="*.sh" to="*" />
</move>
```

Comment: The AntRun scripts themselves copy the original file being moved/renamed, so why would it be read-only? In addition I pointed out that adding a subsequent `<delete>` works, so why doesn't the `<move>` delete the original file when the `<delete>` does? Finally `force` has to do with problems overwriting the _destination_ file, not deleting the original file. (And in this case there is no pre-existing destination file anyway.)